# Proper usage of 'continue' statement

Tags: c++, loops, continue

I have the following list in a text file:

```
ABCD
1234
3456
ABCD
5678
7890
ABCD
4567
```

My code has to go through the text file and each time it sees the string "ABCD", I have to store the 4-digit entries *following* the string into a linked list. I got everything to work but the only section of my code I am having trouble with is getting the entries into separate linked lists.

For example, `1234` and `3456` have to be put into list 1, `5678` and `7890` have to be put into list 2, and `4567` has to be put into list 3. I'm having trouble with the loop I have written to separate these entries and place them into the appropriate lists.

Here is the section of my code:

```
//I have all elements stored initially into a string vector named "words".
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {  //loop through entire vector
    string check = words[i];
    if (isdigit(check[0])) {    //check if first character is a digit
        numbers = words[i];     
        num = stoi(numbers);    //4 digit number converted back to integer
        if (counter == 1) {     
            list1.Add(num);   //Add is a function of type linked list          
        }
        if (counter == 2) {     
            list2.Add(num);
        }
        if (counter == 3) {     
            list3.Add(num);
        }
    }
    else {    //if its not a digit
        counter = counter + 1;    //increase the counter   
    }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
1234
```

Nothing else after the first entry is added to any list. Could someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: All of your `continue`s are redundant, so I don't see their relevance to your algorithm's logic. Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: What do you want to do if `counter` is greater then 1? You store digits only if `counter` is 0 or 1.

Comment: `continue;     //go back to beginning of for loop` - a misleading comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I removed the `continue`s. To make my question clearer, the loop has to go through the list, whenever it comes across a non-digit/comes across an alphabet, it has to move on and store any digits into a list. Then, when you come across another aphabet, the digits that come after that should be stored in the **next* list. and so on

Comment: @AntoJurković In my specific case, the counter won't go above two because in the text file we are given to test our code, there are only three instances where the code will encounter `ABCD`

Comment: Can't reproduce - If words[0] is not a number then nothing is added to list 1 because counter already increased. So with your sample data list1 remains empty and list2 contains 5678 and 7890.

Comment: You have to compare `counter` first with 1 and not 0. Then with 2 and then with 3.

Comment: @user1320881 Ahh I see. I fixed that error. Now, if its not a digit, it should increment the counter. But I just ran the code and I am still getting the same output. Is there anything else wrong?

Comment: @AntoJurković Also fixed that error now and updated the code above. But still getting the same output for some reason

Comment: @ss1111 : Are you sure your lists are storing things properly? print out something to cout above each `add` function as a debugging aid.

Comment: @user1320881 I ran the code step by step and for some reason the `if(counter ==1)` loop is not even being taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the code you have posted, therefore the problem must be with read file or your list class. Here is a working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<list>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = {
        "ABCD", "1234", "3456", "ABCD", "5678", "7890", "ABCD", "4567"  };

    std::list<int> list1, list2, list3;
    int counter = 0;
    for (auto word : words)
    {
        if (isdigit(word[0]))
        {    
            int num = std::stoi(word);
            if (counter == 1) list1.push_back(num); 
            if (counter == 2) list2.push_back(num);
            if (counter == 3) list3.push_back(num);
        }
        else 
        {    
            counter++;    
        }
    }

    for (auto n : list1) std::cout << n << "\n";
    for (auto n : list2) std::cout << n << "\n";
    for (auto n : list3) std::cout << n << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```